# Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module

Tags: node.js, npm

I have been following the tutorial: https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/integrations/google-cloud-platform/

trying to send humidity and temperature data from a Particle Photon to Google Cloud Datastore. The high level architecture is as follows:

[image]

where data is sent from the Photon to Particle Cloud to Google Cloud (Pub/Sub) and to Google Datastore with Node.js as an intermediary.

Everything works to Pub/Sub but as I try to activate the node script (calling: node tutorial.js) I receive errors.

When calling node tutorial.js I receive:

```
$ node tutorial.js 
Authenticating with Google Cloud...
/home/lennart/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:55
    throw error;
    ^

Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system
Expected directory: node-v64-linux-x64-glibc
Found: [node-v57-linux-x64-glibc]
This problem can often be fixed by running "npm rebuild" on the current system
Original error: Cannot find module '/home/lennart/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lennart/node_modules/grpc/src/grpc_extension.js:53:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/lennart/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:145:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
```

I tried `npm rebuild` as suggested in the error message, but this made no change.

Current versions of different packages:

```
$ npm -v  
6.1.0

$ node -v
v10.4.1

$ openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018
```

Previously I had problems with OpenSSL and Node compatability, which could be traced from: `Error undefined symbol: SSL_library_init`. Node v10.4.1 was installed which then seemed to cause the above error.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved this by doing the following:

- Making sure the right version of Node was installed:

  npm install --target=10.0.0 --target_platform=linux --target_arch=x64
- Copying the folder `node-v64-linux-x64-glibc` to two other folders (see below) apart from where it initially had been installed (`/home/lennart/Desktop/Cloud/google-cloud-datastore-tutorial-master/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary`) via the previous command.

`/home/lennart/node_modules/@google-cloud/video-intelligence/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary`
`/home/lennart/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary`

This could probably be solved in a more elegant way, but at least it worked.

Comment: I've been trying to resolve this for two days and - although I didn't need to follow the 2nd step you outlined, of manual copying - the use of the `--target**` flags on an `npm install` is the only thing that finally fixed this issue. Thanks for sharing that bit and death to firebase!!

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue with `node:10-alpine` base image in Docker.
The solution that works for me is running additionally `npm rebuild` on the container's entry point.

`FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD npm rebuild && npm run migrate:run`

Probably running the same `npm rebuild` should resolve the issue locally, or, perhaps this is a problem with `npm` as it cannot fetch the proper binary timely.
Would `yarn` make a difference?

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with npm. Some have resolved the issue by running 'npm rebuild' several times. The above problem has returned after an update, however, instead of "Expected directory: node-v64-linux-x64-glibc" it now says "Expected directory: node-v59-linux-x64-glibc". It cannot be solved with the same method apparently..

Comment: The new problem with "expected directory node-v59-linux-x64-glibc" was solved by using NVM (Node Version Manager) to install an older version of Node (8.11.3, which is the stable version at the moment). This resulted in error "expected directory node-v57-linux-x64-glibc", which was solved in same manner as my previous answer to the problem: by copying the folder from where it was installed to the two other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the NODE&NPM version of reguler user and SUPER USER NODE&NPM versions are same.

Answer (score 0):

For me a simple `yarn --force` did it, once I used `nvm` to switch to the proper node.js version. I had originally done `yarn` with the wrong version.